# Expectation of squared RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all permutations on the set {1,2,...,n}, equipped with the uniform measure. For a permutation $\sigma \in \Omega$ let $X(\sigma)$ denote the number of fixed points by $\sigma$, i.e. 
$$X(\sigma)=card\{1 \leq j \leq n: \sigma(j)=j \}$$.

I computed that $\mathbb{E}[X]=1$ and I am now trying to compute $ \mathbb{E}[X^2] $. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Why is it more difficult for you to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$?

Comment: I am not sure which formula I am supposed to use.

Comment: How did you calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

Answer (score 0):

For $j=1,\dots,n$ define $U_{j}\left(\sigma\right)=1$ if $\sigma\left(j\right)=j$
and $U_{j}\left(\sigma\right)=0$ otherwise.

Then $X=\sum_{j=1}^{n}U_{j}$
and consequently $X^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}U_{i}U_{j}$.

Here $U_{j}^{2}=U_{j}$ and because of symmetry:

$$\mathbb{E}X^{2}=n\mathbb{E}U_{1}+n\left(n-1\right)\mathbb{E}U_{1}U_{2}$$

It remains to find $\mathbb EU_1=P(U_1=1)$ and $\mathbb EU_1U_2=P(U_1=U_2=1)$. Can you do that?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot

Comment: actually, how do we find the probability that $U_1=U_2=1$ ?

Comment: Well, how many permutations are there? And how many of them leave $1$ and $2$ untouched?

Comment: There are n! permutations, (n-1)! leave 1 fixed and (n-2)! leave 2 fixed?

Comment: Exactly $(n-2)!$ of the $n!$ permutations (that all have equal probability to occur) leave the elements $1$ **and** $2$ (belonging to set $\{1,\dots,n\}$) fixed. So the probability of this event is...